# Change U+200B and U+200C to something else?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, formatting

When I was commenting on [this post by @GregMartin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112003/60043), I realized U+200B and U+200C characters had been inserted in my code, making it non-functional.

[This meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170970) states that those characters are inserted when 80 non-space characters are entered. However, this may be problematic on this site, as it deals with code and bytecounts. Removing the feature is not an option because it breaks formatting.

Can this formatting feature be changed, as suggested in the aforementioned meta post?

Comment: I don't think this is a [meta-tag:support] question, ti's asking to change this. Rollback if I misunderstood.

Comment: If you read that mSE post, you'll realize that they don't really have a nice cross-browser solution to that problem yet. So it's not going to happen. [See this recent comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert#comment918962_170970)

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Based on [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307435/361699) on Meta Stack Exchange, this is now fixed.